# How to rotate a div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rotatetransform

I want to rotate this div 180 degres when user clicks a button.

```
<div class="game-wrapper">
...
</div>
```

I have this code in JavaScript.

```
$scope.rotate = function () {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("game-wrapper");
    x.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined
>
> at Scope.$scope.rotate (controllers.js:421)

I'm also using AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

The regular DOM API doesn't work like the jQuery API (implicit looping of all elements in collection when setting values).

Your HTML suggests there is only one of this element with the class. So you could just get the first element with `x[0]`.

However, for general advice you need to loop over the collection returned and apply it to each individual element.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("game-wrapper");
Array.protoype.forEach.call(x, function(y) {
   y.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
});
```

Use `Array.from()` to turn your collection into a regular array if your platforms support it or you're transpiling to ES4.

Answer (score 0):

Like @alex says. But apart from that, mind that `element.style.transform` won't work in every browser as you need to add the prefixes for every browser you support:

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "";
element.style.MozTransform = "";
element.style.msTransform = "";
element.style.OTransform = "";
element.style.transform = "";
```

The same goes for when you do it with CSS:

```
// loop from Alex' answer
Array.protoype.forEach.call(x, function(y) {
   y.classList.add('rotated');
});
```

CSS:

```
.rotated {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check code,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <div class="container-div {{rotateclass}}" ng-class="{{rotateclass}}">Hello</div>
    <button ng-click="handleAnchorClick()">Click me</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

and controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
```

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

```
$scope.handleAnchorClick = function() {
   $scope.rotateclass = "roratediv"
};
```

});

and check the link for preview

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/Sp107XonpFuduCEQyccb?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate it in the following way:
Set your variables to target the elements
Run a function when the button is clicked.
The function takes the style of the div and rotates is by 180 degrees

```
var button = document.querySelector('.button-they-can-click');
var gameWrap = document.querySelector('.game-wrapper');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  gameWrap.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(180deg)';
  gameWrap.style.MozTransform = 'rotate(180deg)';
  gameWrap.style.msTransform = 'rotate(180deg)';
  gameWrap.style.OTransform = 'rotate(180deg)';
  gameWrap.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Hi please refer this link which i use the angular
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Sp107XonpFuduCEQyccb?p=preview

Comment: Not only does your link do nothing for me, but it's massively over complicating the problem. Also, it's usually best to post your code here, rather than just linking out (Otherwise if the outside site goes down, your answer becomes useless)

Comment: I want to rotate this div 180 degres when user clicks a button. this is the problem u stated and in the link which i mentioned its resloved , what else u expect or whats wrong in that

Comment: I'm not the original asker, however as I stated in my response, your link doesn't work for me. I click the button and nothing happens. Since I'm on the latest version of Chrome, it's safe to say this probably wont work for the majority of people.

Comment: please check the above reply